# Why delimiter on char? c-based

Tags: c#, c++, c, char, literals

I was writing some code in C# the other day and it got me thinking. If a char literal can only have 1 char (or a delimited character) then why do we need the closing delimiter?

For example, currently we need to write:

```
char character = 's';
```

And there is no circumstance where this can work (obviously):

```
char character = 'sa';
```

Then why do we have to put the closing `'` rather than have it implied? Eg:

```
char character = 's;
char anotherCharacter = '\';
```

Readability would only be impacted because we are used to the current standard (not necessarily because this way is less readable).

Comment: How would space, tab, other whitespace, unicode literals, and semi-colon work? I can only assume for readability sake and to reduce general psychiatrist costs for developers the world-over since they can maintain some sense of sanity.

Comment: You know, that multicharacter literal is a valid thing.

Comment: `'\040'`, `'\x20'`, `'Rsrc'` - the last one is a 4-byte integer literal in C

Comment: @D.Shawley, Not necessarily four bytes, but yeah, it's an `int`.

Comment: @chris resource types in the older Apple Toolbox API used this fact to make very readable integer literals :)

Comment: @D.Shawley Interesting. Put it in the answers (and maybe elaborate on what this is - never seen that before) and I will tick :)

Comment: @D.Shawley, Well, it's 6.4.4.4/10 if you want the standard text.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I didn't event know you could put a tab character in a char literal. Needless to say, now that I know this... my code wont change one bit! But what you say affects readability of bad code, not functionality (unless I misunderstood).

Comment: Yeah, I kinda realized that _that_ particular argument could just as easily be applied to the existing rules. I still think it would make code much more unreadable, especially when the `char` used matches C# syntax characters like `()[]{};` and the like when used in expressions or method calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, Java and C++ the answer is simple:

Because that's the way it was implemented in C.

Why was it implemented in C that way?

Who knows? There may be some implementation quirk in the first C parser/compiler that made this choice obvious; I'm betting that K&R just didn't think about it. A single quote just looks weird.

Comment: +1 probably the most accurate and correct response I have seen so far. I wonder why they did it like that in C. And a single quote looks weird because we are used to seeing it used as a start and end delimiter instead of just a prefix (like 0x0000).

Comment: They did it that way in C because that's how B (C's predecessor) did it. It's also how BCPL did it, the language on which B was based. I have zero knowledge on how CPL did it.

Comment: @paxdiablo yeah, you're right and the decision was probably influenced by Algol 60, COBOL, Fortran and any other language of the time.

Comment: @paxdiablo IIRC, CPL did not distinguish between a character and a string of length 1.  Strings were wrapped in single quotes there.  I've been trying to track down where the concept of a character as opposed to a string entered the programming language world.

Answer (score 7):

1. It's a convention
2. Characters are not necessarily represented in one character, in this unicode world
3. Control / escape sequences can be longer than one character (e.g. '\0x1a' )

Comment: I did have an example of escaped characters in the question.

Comment: Imagine a case where your output would be used to determine the format of text in a Terminal. You would need the escape character, which is '\033' in octal. Obviously, the only representation consists of four characters. :D

Comment: @angel As stated, valid escape sequences would work the same as before (minus the apostrophe at the end).

Comment: A character is always represented as one character assuming any sane definition of character.  The problem is _mixing_ definitions of characters.

Answer (score 1):

`'abcd'` is a multi-character literal; it's type is `int`, and its value is implementation defined. The closing `'` is needed to mark the end of the literal.

Comment: I noticed that this doesn't work for `long long int` and other sized integers. Ie with literals greater than 4 `char`s.

Answer (score 0):

The existing C syntax defines *character-constant* as:

> *character-constant*:
>
> `'` *c-char-sequence* `'`
>
> `L'` *c-char-sequence* `'`

Your question boils down to why this couldn't be defined instead as:

> *character-constant*:
>
> `'` *c-char*
>
> `L'` *c-char*

Well, it could - in the sense that this would still be a consistent parseable grammar, and you'd still be able to express single-character constants.  What you couldn't do is express multiple-character constants (eg. `'ab'`) - these are legal, but have a value that is implementation-defined.

I suspect that the true reason is simply aesthetics.  For example, there's also no reason in theory why parantheses are needed around the conditional expression of an `if` statement either.

Comment: Some languages (such as Basic-like languages) don't have parentheses around if and similar structures.

Comment: @MrUniverse: Right - at some point it's just about what the original language designers thought looked nice.

Comment: Definitely seems to be what it all boils down to.